# Signed an offer but manager not responding

Tags: new-job, stress

Signed an offer and gave notice to my current company. My start date will be next Monday. According to the offer package, my manager should get in touch with me before I start. I am so stressful since I tried to email my manager last week and followed up today for more details on my first day but got no response. What should I do…

Answer (score 6):

> What should I do

Relax and prepare yourself for Monday. The manager will contact you or not. Either way you just need to focus on creating a good impression on Monday.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Kilisi's answer:

Call them. Even the main number - explain the situation and then ask who might be able to answer a few key questions you need confirmation on before your start date.

The Manager may have been taken away sick or had a sudden leave of absence - if you have a signed offer, IIRC, it's legally binding - so worst case scenario is you just walk in on Monday with your offer and ask around until someone can assist.

Comment: If you have a signed copy. But the OP did not mention having a signed copy. If you sign an offer but you don't get a signed copy from the company then it's not a binding contract. A contract needs to be signed by both parties. some companies send you an offer that you sign and then they return you a signed copy afterwards. But if you just sign a contract and don't receive a signed copy is not binding.